# Elasticsearch: restrict result to documents with exact match

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Currently I trying to restrict results of Elasticsearch (5.4) with the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "apache log Linux",
          "type": "most_fields",
          "fields": [
            "message",
            "type"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "client": "test"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This returns every document that contains `"apache"`, `"log`", or `"linux"`. I want to restrict the results to documents that have a field "client" with the **exact** specified value, this case: `"test"`. However, this query returns all the documents that contain "test" as value. A document with `"client": "test client"` will also be returned. 
I want to restriction to be exact, so only the documents with `"client": "test"` should be returned and not `"client": "test client"`.

After testing a bunch of different queries and lots of searching, I can not find a solution to my problem. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `keyword` part of your `client` field, since this is 5.x and, **by default**, the `keyword` is already there:

```
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "client.keyword": "test"
    }
  }
```

Comment: The field `client.keyword` does not returns results. I checked the mapping of my index and found that the `client.raw` is typed as `keyword`. So it is true that 5.x maps keyword as default. Using `client.raw` therefore solves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set a mapping on your index specifying that your `client` field is a [`keyword` datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/keyword.html).

The mapping request could look like

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "client": {
          "type":  "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the `keyword` datatype solves my problem. I use logstash to write data to Elasticsearch and are therefore not able to change the mapping of a field. However the keyword mapping is already present in the .raw by default.